# Restart code that has been paused using Stop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to restart VBA code that has been paused using `Stop`.

I have this to reset the code:

`Application.VBE.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=228).Execute`

I want to replace 'ID:=228' with the ID of the 'Run' button.

What is the ID for the Run button?

Comment: The ID of the 'Run' button within the VBE menu is 186 ... but I'm not sure that knowing that is going to help you with your wider problem. You might need to re-phrase your question, or ask a new question.

Comment: If you break the code execution, first you have to Stop the execution of it. Then can again Start it.

Comment: Can't I resume it from the last paused location ? Can I simulate clicking the run button in VBA Code View using some code?

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question similar to this one yesterday, so there are more details here: [Pause/Resume code execution in VBA using a button on a userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809430/pause-resume-code-execution-in-vba-using-a-button-on-a-userform/76815739#76815739)

But the gist is that when you are in Break mode (by executing STOP), you cannot run any VBA code.  My other answer gives an example of how to structure code to to allow you to pause and resume it without calling STOP.